# PostgreSQL limit audit table permission for user

Tags: sql, postgresql

I was creating a Audit trail table where `some_user` can edit a table, Autid table logs it. But  `some_user` cannot edit the audit table

I have the following table `items`. which looks like this

```
|    date    |  id |   s_px   |   c_px   | fee |
+------------+-----+----------+----------+-----+
| 2015-01-01 | 001 | 5355.00  |  5355.00 |   2 |
| 2015-01-01 | 002 | 13240.00 | 13240.00 |   3 |
| 2015-01-01 | 003 | 5840.00  |  5840.00 |   1 |
| 2015-01-01 | 004 | 20.55    |    20.59 |   5 |
| 2015-01-01 | 005 | 64.42    |    64.42 |   6 |
```

I created an `audit_tb` to track any changes for the table `items` with trigger that call a function `audit_function()` for any Insert, Update, Delete.

`audit_function()` insert any changes on `items` table to `audit_tb`.

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger

Everything works fine when I am a `power user` have all access to `items` and `audit_tb`. Problem is `power_user` can also modify the `audit_tb`.

So I created `some_user` which can change `items`, and can only `select` `audit_tb`. 
The Problem is with this `audit_function()` cannot Insert since user `some_user` is limited to `Select` only.

```
ERROR: permission denied for relation audit_tb
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to grand permission to the user

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE mydb TO admin_user;
```

Comment: I don't want the user to be able to modify the `audit_tb`

Answer (score 0):

Create `audit_function()` as the superuser with the option `security definer`. If you do that, the function will run with the privileges of the superuser (=the owner), not with the privileges of the users that triggered the function.